# How to implement the full function of google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I am working to implement the google map in my android app.

So far I have created the map with marker using the tutorial here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

The code is like this:

```
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

Just create marker and move the camera to that point. It works , however, I notice that the google map should have more function e.g. gps, direction, search bar like the screenshot below:

[image]

For the gps I found that I have to add permission in order to open the gps button.

So the problem is: how about search bar and direction button? how to implement those function in android?

Comment: add these permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

Comment: check outthis link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: yes they are for gps , how about direction (blue button ) and search bar? thx

Comment: It looks like `FloatingActionButton (FAB)`

Comment: like that u want http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library/

Comment: Thanks a lot for information. seems I need to customized it ? is that means the android SDK has no API function to enable the direction / searching function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this u want search bar on map. 
[image]